# UIAlertView if Login or Password are empty

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I'm creating simple login page where AlertView needed to be shown if password or login fields are empty.Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Please do some R&D work before asking question here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)login{
    if(username.text.length == 0 || password.text.length == 0){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Complete All Fields" message:@"You must complete all fields to login!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release]
    }
}
```

This should do it.  `-(void)login` is the method attached to some touch event, such as when the user taps a "login" button or something.

`username` and `password` are `UITextField`s.

Comment: The operators in this statement should probably be logical and not or.

Comment: What is wrong with doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

This problems boils down to two major subproblems;

**How to check if a string is empty**

`NSString` offers a method called `length` which will return the number of characters within that string instance.

---

[NSString Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html):

```
length
```

Returns the number of Unicode characters in the receiver.

```
- (NSUInteger)length
```

*Return Value*

The number of Unicode characters in the receiver.

*Discussion*

The number returned includes the individual characters of composed character sequences, so you cannot use this method to determine if a string will be visible when printed or how long it will appear.

---

Assuming that there is a variable existing called name of type `NSString`.

```
if ([name length] == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"the given name is empty!");
}
```

---

**How to display an alert**

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Error"
                                                message:@"The given name is empty."
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

For more, see the [UIAlertView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html).